# DIfference Between two Clusters

Tags: data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

So, I have a thing to do, but i need an advice how to do that. My data points is: 1,2,9,6,4 and I need to compute distance between clusters. I need to you Euclidean distance.

My answer was: {1,1} = 0.  {1,2}=1 , {1,9} = 8. Am i doing correct or not?

Comment: Euclidean distance on 1-dimensional data does not make sense. There is something wrong in your question.

Comment: So yes, 2-1=1, and 9-1=8, but I'm pretty sure your question wasn't "what is the difference of 2 and 1".

Comment: Guys question gave be this data points:  1,  2,  9,  6,  4                                      and it want from me to calculate distance between two clusters with Euclidean Distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 5 data points, right?

the formulas should be this:

```
square root of ((1-1)²)  = 0
square root of ((1-2)²)  = 1
square root of ((1-9)²)  = 8
```

...so yeah, you're right.

[euclidian distance formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7mV.gif)

Comment: Thank you. After this point I need to find which clusters are merged into new cluster? How to do that ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @ipo how would k-nearestuneighbor work for clustering?

Comment: Note that the square root and the square are redundant, it reduces to simply `abs(a-b)` in the one-dimensional case. That's why Euclidean doesn't make particular sense on 1 dim data.

Comment: There are different ways to do this. For example k-nearest-neighbor or the k-means algorithm. You calculate the euclidian distance between all you're data points for k-nearest-neighbor and look where the amount of k data points "accumulate" (you decide before how big k is). For the k-means algorithm you choose new data points called prototypes and calculate the distance between these prototypes (minimum 2, because 1 makes no sense) and your data points. Whatever algorithm you choose for, the result is nearly the same: the datapoints belongs to the cluster, where the distance is the lowest.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yeah, youre right. In the normal case you've got more then 1 dim for your data points - in this case you will need the square root. For 1 dim it' senseless.